# Не срабатывает пробел в регулярном выражении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Сейчас изучаю регулярные выражения и решил сделать проверку ввода диапазона/подсети IPv4 адресов для дальнейшей обработки.

Проверка выглядит следующим образом:

```
if(preg_match("/^([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\s?)\-(\s?)[0-9]{1,3}$/", $cidr))
```

Предполагаемый ввод должен быть следующим:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-xxx
```

Так же хочу учесть возможные пробелы перед дефисом и после него.

Проблема заключается в том что не срабатывает валидация второго пробела (после дефиса).

> P.S.:
>   Валидация правильности IPv4 `(0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255)` проводится при обработке.

Comment: Проверял это регулярное выражение в `js` - срабатывает хорошо

Comment: А что это был за пробел? Разница в JS и PHP такая: `\s` в JS находит любые пробельные символы, а в PHP - только ASCII. Попробуйте `"/^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\s?-\s?[0-9]{1,3}$/u"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В PHP ваше регулярное выражение работает.

Вставьте следующий код:

```
<?php
$cidr = "123.123.123.123 - 123";
$result = preg_match("/^([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\s?)\-(\s?)[0-9]{1,3}$/", $cidr);
var_dump($result);
```

вот сюда http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/
и получите результат:

```
int(1)
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо. Ошибка была ниже (просто устал)